# Tetrahedron inscribed in a sphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $A$ be a regular tetrahedron centred at origin and let S be the sphere in which $A$ is inscribed.

Now, let $C_1, C_2, C_3$ be the great circles of $S$ given by all the plane of reflection of $A$.

Then There exists six points $X_1 ... X_6$ such that the three great circle intersect.

Also there exist three points $\{ V_1, V_2, V_3 \}$ in $\{X_1 ... X_6\}$ so that  all angles $\angle V_a V_b V_c \leq \pi / 2$.

Finally, I am looking for the angles (Euclidean) $\angle V_a O V_b : a, b \in \{ 1,2,3\} $ where  $O$ is the origin.

At first, I can not see why there are only three great circle although there are six planes of reflection of a regular tetrahedron which are the triangles of one edge and one middle point.